# Retrieve input value from asp.net custom web control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, custom-controls

I'm building a web control for obscuring input values such as SSN.

I have written the control, however, I can't retrieve the input value on postback.

```
[DefaultProperty("Text")]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:Mask runat=server></{0}:Mask>")]
public class Mask: WebControl, INamingContainer {

    const string INPUT_PREFIX = "_input";

    [Bindable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string Text {
        get {
            return text;
        }
        set {
            text = value;
        }
    }

    protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output) {
        output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Id, this.ID);
        
        output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);

        output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "text");
        output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Id, this.ID + INPUT_PREFIX);
        output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Value, this.Text);

     
        output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Input);
        output.RenderEndTag();

        output.RenderEndTag();
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) {
        this.RenderContents(writer);
    }
}
```

I think I have everything right. I've tried implementing ipostbackdatahandler that didn't work either.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to retrieve the value in:

```
 public virtual bool LoadPostData(string postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) {
        text = postCollection[postDataKey + INPUT_PREFIX];
        return false;
    }
```

and register the control as Requires Postback

```
 protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) {
        Page.RegisterRequiresPostBack(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return text;
        }
        set
        {
            text = value;
        }
    }
```

to:

```
   public string Text
   {
      get
      {
         string text = (string)ViewState["Text"];
         return text ?? string.Empty;
      }
      set
      {
         ViewState["Text"] = value;
      }
  }
```